# Styling lightweight picker icons

Tags: codenameone

I have some lightweight pickers, that are date pickers and string pickers.

The icons to move up and down, to confirm and to cancel are styled like Buttons... but in the case of my specific app, the result is graphically unpleasant.

How can I style these Buttons of the lightweight pickers? Thank you

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? In the lightweight picker I'm thinking of there are no buttons.

Comment: Yes, of course, I added screenshots.

Comment: I found the solution: I have only to style the `PickerButton` CSS element.